# When is an option a certain number of strikes in the money? e.g. "two strikes in"?

Tags: options, terminology

What does it mean when someone says:this option is one strike in the money or that option is 2 strikes in the money and so on and so forth?

I understand in the money, at the money, and out of the money, but what is "2 strikes in the money"? If it is a 100 call and the stock price jumps to 110, is it one strike in the money or two strikes in the money?

Is it any use to think of an option as so many strikes in the money as opposed to just in the money?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have traded options, but not professionally. I hadn't come across this terminology, but I expect it counts how far in-the-money, **as an ordinal**, an option is relative to the distinct strike prices offered for the option *series* — a series being the combination of underlying symbol, expiration date, and option type (call/put); e.g., *all* January 2015 XYZ calls, no matter the strike.

For instance, if stock XYZ trades today at $11 and the available January 2015 XYZ calls have strike prices of $6, $8, $10, $12, $14, and $16, then I would expect the $10 call could be called *one* strike in the money, the $8 *two* strikes in the money, etc. Similarly, the $12 and $14 calls would be one and two strikes *out* of the money, respectively. However, if tomorrow XYZ moves to $13, then the $10 previously known as *one* strike in the money would now be *two* strikes in the money, and the $12 would be the new *one* strike in the money.

Perhaps this terminology arose because many option strategies frequently involve using options that are at- or near-the-money, so the "one strike in" (or out) of the money contracts would tend to be those employed frequently? Perhaps it makes it easier for people to describe strategies in a more general sense, without citing specific examples.

However, the software developer in me dislikes it, given that the measurement is relative to both the current underlying price (which changes quickly), and the strike prices available in the given option series. Hence, I wouldn't use this terminology myself and I suggest you eschew it, too, in favor of something concrete; e.g. specify your contract strikes in dollar terms — especially when it matters.